# Removing associated entity JPA (or delete orphan equivalent in EclipseLink)

Tags: jpa, merge, glassfish, eclipselink

I have a question regarding JPA persistence in Glassfish.
Situation: 
I have a Supplier class that has a 1:n bidirectional relation to SupplierAddress. 
I would like to have the following behaviour:
If I remove the SupplierAddress object from the List in the Supplier object and update it via the merge(supplierobject), the SupplierAddress tupel/object should be deleted. Is there an annotation do configure it like this or do I have to delete it manually. 
Any help would be very appreciated.

Greetings

Marcel

Comment: I edited the title so that others searching for this the way I searched will find it easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in JPA.

In Hibernate this is called "delete orphan". Since you work with EclipseLink, I found something like an equivalent:

[`@PrivateOwned`](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_privateowned.htm) - If you remove the reference to a target from a source, then delete the target.

Comment: Was the [`orphanRemoval`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Orphan_Removal_.28JPA_2.0.29) attribute on `@OneToOne` and `@OneToMany` relationships not supported at the time of this post in JPA?